# Chrome window is off position after maximizing

Tags: unity, compiz, multiple-monitors, mouse, google-chrome

when I unmaximize my Chrome window and then maximize it again, it appears to be redrawn incorrectly, see the attached GIF to see for yourself. What is even worse, is that Chrome still thinks the window is positioned correctly, so that the mouse pointer is always ever-so-slightly off (you can see that in the GIF too, pay attention to the hover-status of the back-button).

I think the issue might be similar to the bug described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1306550) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471995/ubuntu-14-04-offset-mouse-clicking-in-browsers), although there is no mention of the visible offset there. I tried all the fixes suggested in these posts, none of them worked for me.

This is really getting on my nerves, I have a dual monitor setup and I frequently move windows from one monitor to the other, which also makes this bug appear (window is unmaximized and then maximized on the other monitor). The bug also appears after the window-spread has been activated.

Can anyone point me in a direction on how to fix this?

- Ubuntu 14.04
- unity 7.2.3
- Google Chrome 41.0.2272.76 (Official Build)

[image: GIF of the bug occuring]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Unity tweak tools and go to Unity -> Switcher. Make sure you have the "Switch between minimized windows" option checked. I had the exactly same issue and fixed in that way. Let me know if this works!